# google app engine OR filter

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

I want to do an OR filter within google app engine.

For example:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    name = db.StringPropery()
    description = db. StringPropery()
```

The following will return all "MyModel" instances with name = steve AND description = "some text"

```
results = MyModel.all().filter("name =", "steve").filter("description =","some text").fetch(10)
```

What syntax do I use to change this to an OR statement?  Or do I need to do two queries and then merge them somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another thread with some answers here:
[app-engine-datastore-does-not-support-operator-or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930966/app-engine-datastore-does-not-support-operator-or)

Not sure how to mark this as a duplicate. Sorry.