# can you search multiple fields at once with datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

in my app that im designing for GAE, i want, shall we say an omni search bar.

as i understand how datastore stores records, its basically a hashmap of hashmaps.  so i have a key, then something that would look (for conceptional simplicity) a string that would be a JSON return for a value.

in relational DB world, if i wanted to search first and last name at the same time i would have to have something like this

```
select * from user where user.firstname like 'bob' or user.lastname like 'bob'
```

with datastore, can i do something like

```
select from user where user.anyfield like 'bob'
```

and it would search all the fields of the user entity automatically returning any record where either user.firstname and/or user.lastname was like 'bob'?

Comment: App Engine has neither an `or` nor a `like`.  There are suitable workarounds for both - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930966/app-engine-datastore-does-not-support-operator-or/931193#931193, http://stackoverflow.com/q/47786/70492, respectively.

Comment: @hyperslug You should post that as an answre. @scphantm There's nothing preventing you from filtering on multiple properties in App Engine - subject to the restrictions hyperslug mentions.

Answer (score 2):

App Engine does not support `OR`, but as Nick suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930966/app-engine-datastore-does-not-support-operator-or/931193#931193), you can accomplish the same by doing a query for firstnames and another for lastnames and combining the results.

You also cannot directly do a `LIKE` comparison, but you can do a "starts with" query, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47786/google-app-engine-is-it-possible-to-do-a-gql-like-query/1096744#1096744).

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution that exactly does what you need. It uses list properties and Relation Index Entities.

Example of the implementation using Objectify you can find in my blog [here](http://novyden.blogspot.com/2011/02/efficient-keyword-search-with-relation.html). To learn more about Relation Index Entities see this Google IO [track](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/BuildingScalableComplexApps.html).