# Doing a "IN Array" query on google app engine datastore with golang

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

Is there a way to do a query with `ids []int64` on datastore? I've tried the following with no avail.

1. Errors out

   ```
   q := datastore.NewQuery("Category").Filter("Id IN", ids)
   ```
2. Just gets me all the the categories in the datastore

   ```
   for _, id := range ids {
       q.Filter("Id =", id)
   }
   ```

**After icza's answer**

```
var keys []*datastore.Key

for _, id := range ids {
    keys = append(keys, datastore.NewKey(c, "Category", "", id, nil))
}

categories := make([]Category, len(keys))
err := datastore.GetMulti(c, keys, categories)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

Comment: I think you should take a look at testsu's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930966/app-engine-datastore-does-not-support-operator-or)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally `"IN"` filters are not supported by the Datastore. The documentation of [`Query.Filter()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Query.Filter) lists the allowed operators:

```
">", "<", ">=", "<=", or "="
```

What you can do is execute a *separate* query for each of the elements in the array you want to filter by. Also if the elements are in a continous range, you can substitute the `IN` with `id>=min` and `id<=max`. E.g.:

```
ids := []int64{1,2,3,4}
q := datastore.NewQuery("Category").Filter("Id>=", 1).Filter("Id<=", 4)
```

Also note that while the `IN` is not supported in general, if the property is the entity key itself, you can get a list of entities specified by an array of their keys using the [`datastore.GetMulti()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#GetMulti) function:

```
func GetMulti(c appengine.Context, key []*Key, dst interface{}) error
```

**Note:**

Your 2nd attempt returns all entities because you call `Filter()` on your query, but you don't store the return value, so the query you end up executing will have no filters at all. `Query.Filter()` returns a derivative query which contains the filter you just specified, you have to use the returned `Query` ongoing. So it should be:

```
q = q.Filter("Id=", id)
```

But even this won't work either: if multiple filters are specified, they will be in logical AND connection so it will most likely give you 0 results as I suspect no category will exists where `Id` is a list and which would contain all the ids you want to filter by.

Comment: using GQL you can also do something like SELECT * FROM survey WHERE survey.candidate.emails contains ''

Comment: There actually now is an `in` and `not-in` filter in Datastore, see [here](https://cloud.google.com/go/docs/reference/cloud.google.com/go/datastore/latest#cloud_google_com_go_datastore_Query_FilterField). Also FYI `Filter` is now deprecated in favour of `FilterField`.