# How to implement 'OR' in Google App Engine datastore filters with Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, filter, google-cloud-datastore

I found an early thread in Java but can't find anything in Python: [App Engine datastore does not support operator OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930966/app-engine-datastore-does-not-support-operator-or)

I would like to filter my query data with two filters but in an 'OR' relationship, such as `filter('privacy =', True) OR filter('user =', current_user)`. How do I do this in Python?

If I can't, what are the better options for me to implement this manually? I tried to get two separate lists and join them manually, but then I have to maintain two cursors and am not sure if this is the best way in terms of performance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The [ndb documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#nest_and_or) describes how to implement OR queries using `ndb.OR`

e.g.

qry = MyModel.query(ndb.OR(MyModel.name == 'foo', MyModel.name == 'bar')

Answer (score 0):

For OR you can use:

```
query = Model.query(ndb.OR(Model.A ==1,Model.B==1))
```

Similarly AND:

```
query = Model.query(ndb.AND(Model.A==2,Model.B==2))
```